Sharing ad account access to other business manager throwing an error (Application does not have the capability to make this api call.)
We are trying to give an option to the user to request there partners to share their assets access like ad account to  requested business account. we are using this api to process this flow
curl -i -X POST \ "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/<businessid>/client_ad_accounts?adaccount_id=act_123&permitted_tasks=%5B%0A%20%20%22MANAGE%22%0A%5D&access_token=User Access Token"

Note: I will provide the details for above in confidential reply.
we have checked the access token we have the required permission like business_manager as per the api document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-asset-management/guides/business-to-business
But we keep getting this error (Application does not have the capability to make this api call.).
Please suggestion if anything we are missing or any special permission required for this api call. However when we try the same process with pages then it works fine.
Your help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!!
I have tried above Curl , I am expecting access sharing should be working as per the facebook api
